# Oracle SQL - Running Sum based on group by and condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have table that looks like

```
ID      SEQ       LABEL     COUNT
1        1           0       3
1        2           0       2
1        3           0       6
1        4           1       2
1        5           0       3
1        6           0       5
2        1           0       2
2        2           1       1
2        3           0       3
```

I would like to create a column called running_count. It calculates cumulative sum of the column count till the Label is 1 and then reset and start cumulative sum again.

Expected Output:

```
ID      SEQ       LABEL1     COUNT1     RUNNING_COUNT
1        1           0       3              3
1        2           0       2              5
1        3           0       6              14
1        4           1       2              16
1        5           0       3              3
1        6           0       5              8
2        1           0       2              2
2        2           1       1              3
2        3           0       3              3
```

I tried the following query

```
SELECT A.*, SUM(COUNT1) over (partition by ID,LABEL1 order by SEQ) as RUNNING_COUNT FROM TABLE_1 A
```

The problem here is that the cumulative sum stops in previous row(Seq) for Label = 1. I need to get the running sum till Label = 1 for Each ID based on Seq.

The Wrong Output I am getting

```
ID      SEQ       LABEL1     COUNT1     RUNNING_COUNT
1        1           0       3              3
1        2           0       2              5
1        3           0       6              14
1        4           1       2              2
1        5           0       3              3
1        6           0       5              8
2        1           0       2              2
2        2           1       1              1
2        3           0       3              3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a first window `sum()` to define the groups, then use it as partition for the outer query:

```
select 
    t.*,
    sum(count1) over(partition by id, grp order by seq) running_count
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(label) over(partition by id order by seq desc) grp
    from mytable t
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de536e5a3f73b9cd035f5d852d82e434)**:

```
ID | SEQ | LABEL | COUNT1 | GRP | RUNNING_COUNT
-: | --: | ----: | -----: | --: | ------------:
 1 |   1 |     0 |      3 |   1 |             3
 1 |   2 |     0 |      2 |   1 |             5
 1 |   3 |     0 |      6 |   1 |            11
 1 |   4 |     1 |      2 |   1 |            13
 1 |   5 |     0 |      3 |   0 |             3
 1 |   6 |     0 |      5 |   0 |             8
 2 |   1 |     0 |      2 |   1 |             2
 2 |   2 |     1 |      1 |   1 |             3
 2 |   3 |     0 |      3 |   0 |             3
```